# Restoring the position of wrapper on the next click

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I have a toggle button, menu, & a wrapper containing all div below the menu. When I click the button, the menu drops down & the wrapper too moves down to avoid overlapping. But I am unable to restore the position of wrapper on the next click. Could anyone please help me with the code.

Here is the code:

```
<title> English Grammar Exercises </title>
```

```
<div id='container'>

    <div id="header"> English Grammar Exercises </div>

    <div class="toggle-area">

        <label for="toggle">

            <span> </span>
            <span> </span>
            <span> </span>


        </label>

    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

    <div id="menu">

        <ul>

            <li> <a href="#"> Menu1 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu2 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu3 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu4 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu5 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu6 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu7 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Menu8 </a> </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="image"> <img src="images/pic1.png" alt="image"> </div>

        <div id="text"> Grammar Exercises </div>

        <div id="section">

            <div id="index">

                <ul>

                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence1 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence2 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence3 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence4 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence5 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence6 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence7 </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Sentence8 </a> </li>

                </ul>

             </div>

            <div id="content">
                <p> Exercises for Board Examinations </p>

                <div id=content-a>

                    <img src="images/set1.jpeg" alt="image1">
                    <img src="images/set2.jpeg" alt="image2">
                    <img src="images/set1.jpeg" alt="image3">

                </div>

                <div id="content-b">

                    <img src="images/set1.jpeg" alt="image4">
                    <img src="images/set2.jpeg" alt="image5">
                    <img src="images/set1.jpeg" alt="image6">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer"> </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you also post your html and styling, will make it easier to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could use something like `if ($('#wrapper').css('top') == '320px')` to check if the wrapper has already been moved, and if it has you can animate it back to the start position

Comment: @tshimkus It would be better to use a class toggle for that. It's usually better to add and remove classes than manipulating the css directly. You can add a timer as the second parameter for add class `$(this).toggleClass('foo',1000)`, will have 1000ms transition.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you're wrapper would be overlapping is if you're setting everything to absolute, which is generally not a great idea for responsive web development.

Instead, it all in a container, and assign it a position relative.
Inside of that, your absolute elements will still be absolute, but relative to their parent container.

Then if you set your menu position and height, and your wrapper position (and height if you want or it can be given its height by its content) then your content won't overlap. Then simply toggle between the two states.

(Your question wasn't very clear about the intended behaviour, but the answer below should allow you to manipulate it to do what you want, styling wise)

```js
$('document').ready(function() { // This is not needed as long as the script is at the bottom of the page

  $('#toggle').on('click', function() { // When you click on the toggle button

    $('.menu, .wrapper').toggleClass('active'); // Toggle the active variants of menu and wrapper

  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper.active {
  //top: 320px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='toggle' role='button' type='button'>Toggle</button>
<div class='container'>
  <div id='menu' class='menu'>MENU</div>
  <div id='wrapper' class='wrapper'>Wrapper</div>
</div>
```